# Why when i write ItemListView it gives me error?

Tags: c#, android, xaml

I'm working on a job about checking in and out of a school. And when I write ListViewItem this always gives an error:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Alunos WHERE EntradaSaida = 0", conn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataRow dr = dt.Rows[i];

    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(dr["ID"].ToString());
    item.SubItems.Add(dr["Nome"].ToString());
    item.SubItems.Add(dr["Sobrenome"].ToString());
    item.SubItems.Add(dr["TurmaID"].ToString());
    item.SubItems.Add(dr["Data"].ToString());
    lvEntrada.Items.Add(item);
}
if (lvEntrada.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
{
    conn.Open();

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Alunos SET ID =@ID EntradaSaida =@Entrada, Data = @Data ", conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", DateTime.Now);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Entrada", 1);

        int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Post it as text. Also, where are you creating your SQL connection object?

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

at the top of your cs file.

Or you know what else.... don't pass in a parameter to your listView...

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
item.SubItems.Add(dr["ID"].ToString());
item.SubItems.Add(dr["Nome"].ToString());
item.SubItems.Add(dr["Sobrenome"].ToString());
item.SubItems.Add(dr["TurmaID"].ToString());
item.SubItems.Add(dr["Data"].ToString());
lvEntrada.Items.Add(item);
```

What is `lvEntrada`? does it have a property named `Items`?